# Volvo v60 Shake when shifting to D

Tags: automatic-transmission, volvo, v60

I recently bought a 2012 V60 D3, the whole car shake when I shift from `P` to `D`. After some research online they say it's a Design flaw with Aisin transmission that cause an internal leak. Does anyone have additional information about this issue or potential fixes? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 thank you.

Comment: How long does it shake for, a few seconds, or all the time you are stationary in D?

Comment: @HandyHowie its momentary that is when I shift to `D` I feel a strong shake, It's exactly the same in this [youtube short](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/bsbGfF8Qljs)